# Course on machine learning on application in material science

Tags: machine-learning, education

Are there any online courses available that is on the application of ML in material science? Any recommendations?

Comment: Have a look at SchNet (https://schnetpack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). It has a really great documentation and sample tutorials.

Comment: Not a recommendation on a specific course, workshop, webinar, etc (and for this reason, a comment only).  But it is possible to query the publishers with the keywords, e.g., [`Machine Learning in Materials Science`](https://pubs.acs.org/action/doSearch?AllField=Machine+Learning+in+Materials+Science) which was in part *automatically* suggested/completed typing only the first two into the quick search mask for the journals by the American Chemical Society. For now/today, the search yields 8k+ entries, 362 alone for publications in the Journal of Chemical Education.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Machine Learning for Physicists

If you wish for a general introduction to a number of ML concepts and tools useful in physics (not entirely specific to "material science"), and taught for physicists, I recommend [the online course "Machine Learning for Physicists" by Florian Marquardt.](https://pad.gwdg.de/s/HJtiTE__U#)

All the lectures are [available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLemsnf33Vij4eFWwtoQCrt9AHjLe3uo9_), and the course is shipped with a number of tutorials which can be found on [the associated github repository.](https://github.com/FlorianMarquardt/machine-learning-for-physicists)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 5):

Andrew White's resource on deep learning for molecules and materials, https://dmol.pub/, is not technically a course, but has enough volume and importantly enough python examples to have been useful to me. Compared to the series by Florian Marquardt, it covers more advanced topics including physical symmetry operations (invariance and equivariance) within machine learning.